# Run database updates on live Magento store?

Tags: mysql, database, magento-1.5, locks

I have been asking a few questions recently to work out how to change our Magento store's product codes.

The answer was to run this command within phpmyadmin:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` SET `sku` =  RIGHT(CONCAT('00000000', sku), 8)
```

It worked perfectly, changing all of our product codes from:

```
63
3433
432
42342343
```

to:

```
00000063
00003433
00000432
42342343
```

The problem is; everytime I run that command it correctly changes the product codes - but all products are then 404'ing. I then refreshed the indices and found that the were locked. I got the following error:

```
Cannot initialize the indexer process.
```

so I ran the following commands via SSH:

```
rm -rf downloader/pearlib/cache/*
rm -rf downloader/pearlib/download/*
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/session/*
rm -rf var/report/*
rm -rf var/tmp/*
rm -rf var/locks/*
```

but the index processes still wouldn't run. I have now completely messed up the database and am waiting for a support tech to try and fix the problem. I will likely be recovering the database from the backup I took before I ran the SQL command.

I am trying to work out how to run this SQL command without messing the Magento (1.5) locks etc. up so that the products don't 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the answer was simple.

1. Disable all cache options
2. Re-index the indices.
3. Run the SQL command.
4. Re-index the indices.
5. Refresh then re-enable the cache

Hope this helps someone else in future!